# Centering a button/text in a table

Tags: html, centering

Tried everything I could think of and can't center align the "MORE INFORMATION" box. Internet searches (including here), had a lot of answers and none worked.

```html
<tr>
  <td data-th="Product Details" class="productDetails"></td>
  <td style="align:center" data-th="Data" class="Data"><a class="btn alt misc" href="http://glasscapacitors.com/glass-capacitor-overview/"><h3> <font color= "#ffb300">MORE INFORMATION</font></h3></a></td> 
  <td data-th="Similar Parts" class="similarParts">%%Panel.SideProductRelated%%</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center your "More Information" title, you need to add `text-align: center;` to your `.misc` a tag.

```css
a.misc {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td data-th="Product Details" class="productDetails"></td>
  <td style="align:center" data-th="Data" class="Data"><a class="btn alt misc" href="http://glasscapacitors.com/glass-capacitor-overview/"><h3> <font color= "#ffb300">MORE INFORMATION</font></h3></a></td> 
  <td data-th="Similar Parts" class="similarParts">%%Panel.SideProductRelated%%</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Appreciated. Couldn't get that to work, maybe because there are previous rows in the table?

Comment: @MikeMoran you may have been applying the styles to the wrong div. :)

Comment: Much appreciate the answer Hunter, and noted for the future. I couldn't get that to work, maybe because there are previous rows in the table? For row three, I changed to "text-align" and that did it. Other rows I just used "align". Hmmm. Learning! All self taught so it's quite a curve.    (Thanks for the additional tip on the check mark- new to SO)